# How to distribute an array to smaller arrays randomly?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to create same sized smaller arrays from a big array. But items should distribte randomly. I can distribute by order like following:

```
int[] source = new[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 };
int i = 0;
int chunkSize = 3;
var result = source.GroupBy(s => i++ / chunkSize).Select(g => g.ToArray()).ToArray();

// [10,20,30][40,50,60][70,80,90]
```

But result should be random like: `// [90,20,50][70,30,60][40,80,10]`
Can I do it using linq?

Comment: The same as what you have, but `OrderBy` before the `GroupBy`. The `OrderBy` should use `Random`.

Comment: before GroupBy add OrderBy random

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Randomize a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following implements the suggestions in the comments to add an `OrderBy` clause. There are, of course, other ways to achieve the result, but this is likely the simplest way using LINQ, as requested.

```
int[] source = new[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 };
int i = 0;
int chunkSize = 3;
Random r = new Random();
var result = source.OrderBy(x => r.Next()).GroupBy(s => i++ / chunkSize).Select(g => g.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shuffle any 1D array with [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt). 
If you modify it to return `IList<T>` instead of `void`, you can append it into your query:

```
var result = source.Shuffle().GroupBy(...)
```

Comment: The Shuffle has to be done at the beginning of the Linq query not when the array is already cut in parts

Comment: I don't really see any problems with that either. Just do `var result = source.Shuffle().GroupBy(...)`.

Comment: Your first method random the small part of the rule. It will be [20, 30, 10], [40, 60, 50] ... The OP want a random at the beginning

Comment: Yeah, that's right, I'm gonna edit my comment into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following.

```
var arr = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 6, 6, 7, 1, 1, 0 };
var sizeOfResultArray = 3;
var result  = arr.ChunkBy(sizeOfResultArray);
```

The extension methods are defined as

```
public static class Extensions
{

    private static Random rng = new Random();  
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> ChunkBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int chunkSize) 
    {
        return source.Shuffle()
            .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
            .GroupBy(x => x.Index / chunkSize)
            .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
            .ToList();
    }
    public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)  
    {  
        var collection = list.ToList();
        int n = collection.Count();
        while (n > 1) 
        {  
            n--;  
            int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
            T value = collection[k];  
            collection[k] = collection[n];  
            collection[n] = value;  
        } 
        return collection;
    }
}
```

The Shuffle is a Fisher-Yates shuffle implementation by Grenade [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt)

Answer (score -1):

You need to randomize and then group.  Code below should work

```
            int[] source = new[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 };
            Random rand = new Random();
            int[] random = source.Select(x => new { num = x, rand = rand.Next() }).OrderBy(x => x.rand).Select(x => x.num).ToArray();
            int groupsize = 3;
            int[][] groups = random.Select((x, i) => new { num = x, index = i })
                .GroupBy(x => x.index / groupsize)
                .Select(x => x.Select(y => y.num).ToArray())
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: No.  To sort you need array of  pairs {10, 12}, {20, 4} {30, 7} {40, 8} {50, 3} {60, 5} {70, 3} {80, 55} {90, 20}

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dIStUh might be an example of what I mentioned.